# Anti spam on Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007, spam, filtering

I have just installed an exchange 2007 server. We are not using the edge server role. In Exchange 2007 are there enabled any out the box anti spam features? I can't see antyhing relating to anti spam managment, but from certain delivery notications, the server "seems"to be filtering certain messages as spam. Excuse me if the question is not very clear, can someone help me out? I am mainly interested to know if the antispam is enabled as an out of the box feature.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the anti-spam component is enabled by default. This article shows you how to enable it.

http://www.petri.co.il/install-anti-spam-exchange-2007.htm

Comment: It doesn't require an Edge server if you're running the Mailbox, CAS, and Hub roles on the same server without an Edge server (single server installation), as referenced in the link I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can [enable Sender ID](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.12.sidf.aspx) (basically just SPF checking) if you install an Edge box; but I cringe at calling that spam filtering.

Exchange 2007+ is really mean to have the various parts (storage, transport, relaying) separated. Several third party filters I've seen will only install on Edge boxes; though I'm sure there's plenty that will work in your environment too.

Comment: +1. For the most part this is true but not every organization has the budget, expertise, or email volume to justify installing each role on a separate server, which Microsoft has accounted for, which is why you can install The Mailbox, CAS, and Hub Transport roles on a single server and operate without an Edge server.